# How to use DataGrip SQL formatter to align USING/ON clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, formatting, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

How can I get the`on` or `using` clause to start under the`join` statement indented 2/4 spaces from the start of the`join`?

```sql
-- bad
select *
from table1
  join table 2
using (some_col)
```

```sql
-- bad
select *
from table1
  join table 2
       using (some_col)
```

```sql
-- good
select *
from table`
  join table2
    using (some_col)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, JetBrains IDEs don't support this SQL formatting configuration. There is an open ticket to get it added: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-8061

Answer (score -4):

Your IDE should provide some formatting options, if there aren't any, then i would recommend using an external tool like https://www.sqlinform.com